# Populating a Map<Id,List<Contact>> for a comparison

Tags: apex, list, map

What I am trying to do here is populate a list from a callout to Looker (BI Tool) then create a Map of Salesforce Account IDs to associated Contact Emails. To do this I created this method:

```
public static Map<Id, List<Contact>> lookerById() {
   List<Contact> lookerList = zuoraContactSync.mergeList();
   system.debug(lookerList);
   Map<Id, List<Contact>> lookerByIds = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
   for(Contact con : lookerList) {
           List<Contact> contacts = lookerByIds.get(con.Email);
           system.debug(lookerByIds);
           lookerByIds.put(con.AccountId, contacts);      
       }                 
       //status__c is ROLE

   system.debug(lookerByIds.size());
   system.debug(lookerByIds);
   return lookerByIds;
}


   return lookerByIds;
}
```

When I use the put on this line :

```
lookerByIds = put(con.AccountId, contacts);
```

I am returned with an incorrect method signature error.

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(Id, List<Contact>) from the type ClassName
```

I am reasonably certain I have the right logic to do this... mostly. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be doing `lookerByIds.put(con.AccountId, contacts);` This should solve your issue.

Comment: Always the small stuff. Seems my if comparison is also off as it returns 0.

Comment: Yes, it would get you 0 as you have initialized `lookerByIds` at line #3 and haven't assigned any values. Check your business logic to make sure you are comparing a Map/List that contains your Account Ids.

Comment: The list comes from an external source and contains only the SFDC Account Id and the contact Email. The goal is to compare the emails provided to existing contacts for a given account Id and then create a new contact for it if it does not exist. I have revised it to assign values now but the ID is invalid as I have no contactID to provide it.

Comment: You would get another error message as your Line #6 doesn't have any records as you have created `lookerByIds` at line #3 and didn't assign any values. I would reassess the business need and try to implement step-by-step. This way, we could get more control on the data that is being retrieved. Try going through: [Apex documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_writing.htm).